# Rails 4: Joins in ActiveRecord relation lambdas not include when doing a join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm creating a Revision system for a project where a base table contains the current revision for a given id, and a revision table contains the data tagged with a given revision, eg:

```
foos
  - id
  - revision

foo_revisions
  - foo_id
  - revision
  {data}
```

For relations between these I have used the lamda syntax to specify conditions on the relation like this:

```
class Article
   belongs_to :product, ->{ joins(:base).where("products.revision = product_revisions.revision") }, :class_name=> "Product::Revision", :primary_key => :product_id
```

Where article is not revisioned, but product is (Product::Revision is the model that contains the actual data, and is a ActiveRecord::Base mapping to product_revisions, while Product maps to products).

The :base relation is from Product::Revision to Product

This works fine for the normal things like

```
a = Article.find(..)
a.product
```

which products the sql (a.product only)

```
SELECT `product_revisions`.* FROM `product_revisions`
   INNER JOIN `products` ON `products`.`id` = `product_revisions`.`product_id`
   WHERE `product_revisions`.`product_id` = 406
   AND (products.revision = product_revisions.revision) ORDER BY `product_revisions`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
```

But when I do Article.joins(:product) it fails, since it doesn't join in the products table:

```
SELECT `articles`.* FROM `articles` INNER JOIN `product_revisions`
    ON `product_revisions`.`product_id` = `articles`.`product_id`
    AND (products.revision = product_revisions.revision)
```

with the error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'products.revision' in 'on clause'
```

To me it seems like ActiveRecord simply ignores the joins in the lamba when it does the joins query, which seems stupid. Is this a bug, or is there a better/correct way to do this?

Comment: Isn't the lambda supposed to be the last argument to `belongs_to`, or passed in as a conventional `do...end` block?

Comment: Yeah, I was confused by that at first too, but this seems to be the correct syntax: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb#L1393

Comment: Interesting, but that's also for when you need to evaluate the string in the context of a particular instance. I don't see that in your example here.

Comment: Yes, but as I have understood it this is the only way to specify a condition to a relation in rails 4.

Comment: Yes, in rails 4, you can no longer pass distinct order, conditions, etc. parameters to the `belongs_to` method. Instead, you must pass a Proc as the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar problem. Any joins specified in a lambda for a has_many are silently ignored.

I found this in the Rails issues that solves the problem for me:
https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/11518

The author mentions the problem occurring when there is an order clause but I think this muddies the water - it makes no difference whether there is an order clause or not.

I cannot say whether this is a bug or intended behaviour but I suspect the former.